# C# with SQL Database Data in PayPal Smart Button Order List

Tags: c#, sql, paypal, webforms

I am working on a C# Web Forms project where I have created a Class to handle various functions of a shopping cart that I am integrating with the new PayPal Smart Buttons using the PayPalCheckoutSdk. Inside of my ShoppingCartActions Class I am running a function that displays the total price of an item based on quantity; everything works fine with this code:

```
public decimal GetTotal()
        {
            ShoppingCartId = GetCartId();
            // Multiply product price by quantity of that product to get        
            // the current price for each of those products in the cart.  
            // Sum all product price totals to get the cart total.   
            decimal? total = decimal.Zero;
            total = (decimal?)(from cartItems in _db.ShoppingCartItems
                               where cartItems.CartId == ShoppingCartId
                               select (int?)cartItems.Quantity *
                               cartItems.Product.UnitPrice).Sum();
            return total ?? decimal.Zero;
        }
```

I am able to display the value on my Cart Page with the following code:

```
public static string price;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (ShoppingCartActions usersShoppingCart = new ShoppingCartActions())
    {
        cartTotal = usersShoppingCart.GetTotal();
        price = String.Format("{0:c}", cartTotal);
        Lbl01.Text = price;
    }
}
```

Here is where my issue comes in: I am wanting to use this value in an Order Request for Paypal but when I try it will not display a value! Below is OrderRequest:

```
public OrderRequest orderRequest = new OrderRequest()
        {
            CheckoutPaymentIntent = "CAPTURE",

            ApplicationContext = new ApplicationContext
            {
                BrandName = "EXAMPLE INC",
                LandingPage = "BILLING",
                CancelUrl = "https://www.example.com",
                ReturnUrl = "https://www.example.com",
                UserAction = "CONTINUE",
                ShippingPreference = "SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS"
            },
            PurchaseUnits = new List<PurchaseUnitRequest>
                {
                    new PurchaseUnitRequest{
                        ReferenceId =  "ReferenceId1",
                        Description = "Description1",
                        CustomId = "CustomId1",
                        SoftDescriptor = "SoftDescriptor1",
                        AmountWithBreakdown = new AmountWithBreakdown
                        {
                            CurrencyCode = Currency,
                            Value = "110.00",
                            AmountBreakdown = new AmountBreakdown
                            {
                                ItemTotal = new Money
                                {
                                    CurrencyCode = Currency,
                                    Value = price<<<<<<Here is where I try to read the data but no error!
                                },
                                Shipping = new Money
                                {
                                    CurrencyCode = Currency,
                                    Value = "15.00"
                                },
                                Handling = new Money
                                {
                                    CurrencyCode = Currency,
                                    Value = "5.00"
                                },
                                TaxTotal = new Money
                                {
                                    CurrencyCode = Currency,
                                    Value = "10.00"
                                },
                                ShippingDiscount = new Money
                                {
                                    CurrencyCode = Currency,
                                    Value = "10.00"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        Items = new List<Item>
                        {
                            new Item
                            {
                                Name = "Product 1",
                                Description = "Product 1 Description",
                                Sku = "Sku1",
                                UnitAmount = new Money
                                {
                                    CurrencyCode = Currency,
                                    Value = "100.00"<<<<<<<<< I tried here as well but nothing displays!
                                },
                                Tax = new Money
                                {
                                    CurrencyCode = Currency,
                                    Value = "10.00"
                                },
                                Quantity = "1",
                                Category = "PHYSICAL_GOODS"
                            },
                        },
                        ShippingDetail = new ShippingDetail
                        {
                            Name = new Name
                            {
                                FullName = ""
                            },
                            AddressPortable = new AddressPortable
                            {
                                AddressLine1 = "",
                                AdminArea2 = "",
                                AdminArea1 = "",
                                PostalCode = "",
                                CountryCode = ""
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        };
```

How can I set the string value to be read inside of the Order Request? Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: "Value = price" .. price doesn't magically get set, you need to pass the value into your function that is creating `orderRequest`. Also you're going to run into issues since multiple values need to be set and the breakdown's totals must sum to the amount total and the item totals must sum to their breakdown subtotal.

Comment: I kind of figured that is what was going on; I am pretty good with the basics and was able to integrate PayPal in the past but now they have changed everything! What would be the best way to pass the value into this function? I have tried getting the value from labels on the page but that isn't allowed in this function; I've tried passing it as a string which is also not allowed in the function...